# Does a class variable have a right to exist if its value can be calculated using other data?

Tags: class, variables, class-design, modeling

I'll give a minimalist example to explain my question.
Suppose that there is a `Shape` class:

```
public class Shape {
    User user;
    int color;
}
```

and a `User` class:

```
public class User {
    int mood;
}
```

Now suppose that a shape's color depends on the user's mood. Is it redundant for `Shape` to have a `color` field since it can be calculated by accessing its `user`'s mood?

Consider that in a more realistic example accessing the necessary data to calculate the color can be more complex or via a longer sequence of accessors (`color = user.getCat().getCousin().getMood()`). Consider further that these classes may be mapped to a database and (in a way) duplicate data. On the other hand they can be marked as transient.

Color depends on the mood but color is not the same as the mood at all. So including `color` field seems only logical to me, however I cannot wholly justify this design.

Does a class variable have a right to exist if its value can be calculated using other data?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you make color a property, that way you can calculate it or not and the rest of the program won't change.

Calculating it everytime will be slower, add extra code everytime it is being called. Keeping the value will be faster (don't need to calculate everytime) but you add the risk of not having the right value if it isn't updated properly.